# Adding new key value pair in array with for each loop in all the indexes

Tags: php

```
foreach ($api_res['data'] as $item) {
    $services_arr[] = array(
      'name' => $item['name'], 
      'service_code' => $item['service'], 
      'count' => $item['count']
    );
    if($price == 'per_week') {
      $services_arr['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 7);
    } else {
      $services_arr['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 30);
   }      
}
```

RESULT

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => zzz [service_code] => opt82 [count] => 124 ) [price] => 1.4 [1] => Array ( [name] => dddfx [service_code] => opt46 [count] => 78 )
```

It adds price key value in first array index only. I want to add the price in all the indexes.

Comment: Built the array you want, then push that array into your bigger array.

Comment: Yes, you can simply use ```array_push```. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

Working example of @NietTheDarkAbsol said:

```
foreach ($api_res['data'] as $item) {
    $arr = array(
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'service_code' => $item['service'],
        'count' => $item['count']
    );
    if ($price == 'per_week') {
        $arr['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 7);
    } else {
        $arr['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 30);
    }
    $services_arr[] = $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ternary operator

```
foreach ($api_res['data'] as $item) {
    $services_arr[] = array(
      'name' => $item['name'], 
      'service_code' => $item['service'], 
      'count' => $item['count'],
      'price_day' => $item['price_day'] * (($price == 'per_week') ? 7 : 30)
    );     
}
```

or you can handle the index in the foreach

```
foreach ($api_res['data'] as $index => $item) {
    $services_arr[$index] = array(
      'name' => $item['name'], 
      'service_code' => $item['service'], 
      'count' => $item['count']
    );
    if($price == 'per_week') {
      $services_arr[$index]['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 7);
    } else {
      $services_arr[$index]['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 30);
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is simple enough that I will have to encourage you to use a ternary operator and save yourself the hassle.

```
foreach ($api_res['data'] as $item) {
    $services_arr[] = array(
      'name' => $item['name'], 
      'service_code' => $item['service'], 
      'count' => $item['count'],
      'price' => $item['price_day'] * ($price == 'per_week' ? 7 : 30)
   );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of without changing your current code too much using PHP end() and key() functions.

```
foreach ($api_res['data'] as $item) {
$services_arr[] = array(
  'name' => $item['name'], 
  'service_code' => $item['service'], 
  'count' => $item['count']
);

end($services_arr);
$last_index_id=key($services_arr);

if($price == 'per_week') {
  $services_arr[$last_index_id]['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 7);
} else {
  $services_arr[$last_index_id]['price'] = ($item['price_day'] * 30);
}}
```